# Tensorflow interactive prediciton using dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have created a Tensorflow model which uses the Dataset API in order to feed the data into the network.

After the training phase, I would like to restore this model and to perform inference on it once in a while.

Currently I am re initializing the dataset iterator each time, but I'm wondering if there is an alternative way.
Moreover at training time, my dataset contains x and y data, while at prediction time I only have x. As a temporary  solution, I am providing a fake y, but again, this does not seem the best solution.

Here is a pseudocode of what i'm doing:

```
#### NETWORK
input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name="input_x")
input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 2], name="input_y")

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_x, input_y))
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
dataset_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset, name='dataset_init')

x_data, y_data = iterator.get_next()
output = tf.variable(x_data, name='output')

.....

### INFERENCE

while (true):
    x = new_input

    x_operation = session.graph.get_operation_by_name("input_x").outputs[0]
    y_operation = session.graph.get_operation_by_name("input_y").outputs[0]
    dataset_operation = session.graph.get_operation_by_name("dataset_init")
    output_operation = session.graph.get_operation_by_name("output").outputs[0]

    fake_y = np.array([[0, 0]])

    dic = {input_x: x, input_y: y}
    session.run(dataset_operation, feed_dict=dic)

    prediction = session.run(output_operation)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you clarify what model you are using? Can you share some of the model code (or a minimal version of it?) tf.data deals with the input pipeline (how to feed raw data into your model), but is not the model itself. There should be no need to 'restore' a dataset in order to make predictions from a trained model. If you restore the dataset, it will contain the same data as you trained it on, i.e. you will be performing predictions on training data. Instead, you should probably be using different datasets for training and prediction.

Comment: Hi, I will add a complete example as soon as possible. However my data are passed to the dataset as a placeholder, so the restored model will work with new data. Assume that I'm passing raw data to this placeholder and I'm performing preprocessing with the dataset api. This is my use case